# MVC PartialView Load Causing Problems

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am using a .load() to load a partialview. 
It has giving me a whole lot of problems as the DOM gets messed up after the load.

Is there any other way to to load a partial view.

Currently I am using:

```
    $("#stlist").load('@Url.Action("kitsEdit","Speaker")' + '?id=' +  '@Model.spkrid')
```

Comment: you are really bad at tagging , ya know

Comment: `It has giving me a whole lot of problems as the DOM gets messed up after the load.` - Could you elaborate about what you are trying to achieve and how/why/what this *messing* means?

Comment: please paste the rendered view bit containing $('#stlist') part.

Comment: May be you are not returning a partial view from the action. Make sure you are returning *PartialView("")* instead of *View("")*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use jquery

```
<div id="stlist">
    @html.Action("kitsEdit","Speaker", new { id = Model.spkrid })
</div>
```